# Vincent map html output not valid html

Tags: python, html, vincent

I'm writing some code with Python and Vincent to display some map data.

The example from the docs looks like this:

```
import vincent

county_topo = r'us_counties.topo.json'
state_topo = r'us_states.topo.json'

geo_data = [{'name': 'counties',
             'url': county_topo,
             'feature': 'us_counties.geo'},
            {'name': 'states',
             'url': state_topo,
             'feature': 'us_states.geo'}]

vis = vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data, scale=3000, projection='albersUsa')
del vis.marks[1].properties.update
vis.marks[0].properties.update.fill.value = '#084081'
vis.marks[1].properties.enter.stroke.value = '#fff'
vis.marks[0].properties.enter.stroke.value = '#7bccc4'
vis.to_json('map.json', html_out=True, html_path='map_template.html')
```

Running this code outputs an html file, but it's formatted improperly.  It's in some kind of python string representation, `b'<html>....</html>'`.

If I remove the quotes and the leading b, the html page works as expected when run through the built in python server.

What's wrong with my output statement?

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the
>   literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is
>   automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be
>   followed by an 'r' prefix.

You can slice it using:

```
with open('map_template.html', 'w') a f:
    html = f.read()[2:-1]
    f.truncate()
    f.write(html)
```

This will open your `html` file,

```
b'<html><head><title>MyFile</title></head></html>'
```

And remove the first 2 and last character, giving you:

```
    <html><head><title>MyFile</title></head></html>
```